# How can I get rid of duplicated catch() methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

My current codes are as below.

However, I want to make a shared function/module to remove catch() methods.

Is there any way to handle the repeated catch()?

```
import { Token, Post } from "../../entities";
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";

const saveRefreshToken = async (token: Token) =>
    await getRepository(Token)
        .save(token)
        .then((savedToken) => savedToken)
        .catch(() => createInternalServerError()); // repeated catch() method

const savePost = async (post: Post) =>
    await getRepository(Post)
        .save(post)
        .then((post) => post)
        .catch(() => createInternalServerError()); // repeated catch() method

const deleteRefreshToken = async (req: Request): Promise<unknown> => {
    const user = req.user as User;
    return await getRepository(Token)
        .delete({ user })
        .then(() => null)
        .catch(() => createInternalServerError()); // repeated catch() method
};
```

Comment: Simplify to just `.catch(createInternalServerError)` - then there's hardly anything you can abstract over. If you show us where/how you are calling (or otherwise using) these three functions, we might be able to suggest a better way of getting rid of the duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious solutions here:

- Add the catch inside `getRepository` (especially since you seem to **always** create an internal server error for that). Since it's an external function which I assume you can't edit, you can wrap it in a helper function
- Create a helper function `catchHandler` so you only have to repeat `.catch(catchHandler)`

Example of the first solution:

```js
import { Token, Post } from "../../entities";
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";

function getRepositoryWrapped(...args: Parameters<typeof getRepository>) {
    return getRepository(...args).catch(() => createInternalServerError());
}

const saveRefreshToken = async (token: Token) =>
    await getRepositoryWrapped(Token)
        .save(token);

const savePost = async (post: Post) =>
    await getRepositoryWrapped(Post)
        .save(post);

const deleteRefreshToken = async (req: Request): Promise<unknown> => {
    const user = req.user as User;
    return await getRepositoryWrapped(Token)
        .delete({ user })
        .then(() => null);
};
```

*also there's no need for `.then(v => v)` as that does nothing.*

Comment: This does no longer create internal server errors when the `save` or `delete` method call fails

Comment: Hmm you're correct. Then wrapping it won't work unless you do some complex custom-Promise things, obviously not ideal. So it's either my 2nd solution, or wrapping the lambdas instead.